# Real time Change Data Capture in Talend

Tags: talend

I am trying to setup Real time change data capture between two different MySQL databases using Talend Studio. I was able to successfully create a job that uses Publish/Subscribe model that picks up only the changed data from source and populates in the target database.

I could not find the documentation to setup CDC in real time i.e. as soon as a new row is inserted in the source database it will be picked up by the job and populated in target database. The Talend job will be running continuously to look for possible changes in the source.

My question: is scheduling the Talend job using some scheduler for desired interval the only option in this case?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You could also use triggers for Create, Update, Delete on the database and use those triggers to start a process pushing the data somewhere or starting a process.